# Using pointer as an array - C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, types, osdev

I found in C code at [this page](http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones):

```
uint16_t* terminal_buffer;
```

What does it mean? Is it the same as `uint16_t *terminal_buffer;`?
Than variable terminal_buffer is accesed like an array:

```
terminal_buffer[index] = make_vgaentry(' ', terminal_color);
```

Can somebody explain me how it works?
Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you learn the basics of the language before you attempt kernel development.

Comment: @pruky, when you ask whether `uint16_t* terminal_buffer;` is the same as `uint16_t *terminal_buffer;`, you are clearly showing your lack of understanding of the basics of the language. It's very likely that any answer that you get in response to your question will be hard to comprehend without a good understanding of the basics of the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does it mean? Is it the same as `uint16_t *terminal_buffer;`?

Yes it is, the position of the `*` is irrelevant if it's in between the type name and the variable name so you can write `uint16_t   *   terminal_buffer;` if you want, because spaces are ignored.

> Than variable terminal_buffer is accesed like an array:

```
terminal_buffer[index] = make_vgaentry(' ', terminal_color);
```

because this is equivalent to

```
*(terminal_buffer + index) = make_vgaentry(' ', terminal_color);
```

so it's basically a pointer arithmetic operation and a dereference.

Comment: I think there's supposed to be parentheses in there.

Comment: @remyabel No they are not needed.